# ASP Display Dynamic for table images

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I was trying to implement a simple ajax example in asp.
1. The form has a textbox that takes a user name and validates the username after tab out.
2. If user name is valid, a (green tick) sign is shown indicating that username is valid
3. Else, a red cross image is shown
4. A loading animation is shown while ajax request in in progess.

What happens is the red cross image is shown after the textbox with some gap (space) that looks odd. The gap is reserved for animated loading image and green sign image.
How do I remove this. 
I want to show green or red image at the same place in the UI as both of them do not appear at the same time.

[image: screenshot]

The code is:

```
     <table><tr><td>
            User Id:&nbsp;</td><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox></td><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div style="height:30px;width:30px">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100">
              <ProgressTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="loading" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
               </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress></div>
            </td><td>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="15px" 
                ImageUrl="~/valid-icon.gif" ToolTip="Valid User Id" Visible="False" 
                Width="15px" /></td><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="15px" 
                ImageUrl="~/invalid_icon.png" ToolTip="Invalid User Id. Already exists" 
                Visible="False" Width="15px" />
            &nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, Place both Valid-icon and Invalid-icon and div with Update Progress in a single td, no need to place these in separate td. Place Update Progress at last in td. It will solve your problem

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        User Id:&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      <td>          
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="15px" 
            ImageUrl="~/valid-icon.gif" ToolTip="Valid User Id" Visible="False" 
            Width="15px" />

        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="15px" 
            ImageUrl="~/invalid_icon.png" ToolTip="Invalid User Id. Already exists" 
            Visible="False" Width="15px" />

        <div style="height:30px;width:30px">
           <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100">
             <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="loading" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
              </ProgressTemplate>
           </asp:UpdateProgress>
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Almost correct. But the valid-image/invalid-image are not coming in the same row. They are coming slightly above the textbox. May be some more styling is required??? screen shot Image here: http://s11.postimage.org/tie6bye4z/asp_ajax_validation.jpg

Comment: It is coming so, due to the height of the div.. which is set to 30. so if you want to get in same line you can make a class on td like `<td class="setHeight">` and .setHeight { line-height:30px;}, I hope this will help:)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use 'Absolute' position for 'Image1' and 'Image2' control's style property.

Something like,

```
Images.
{  
 position:absolute; 
  height:150px; 
  width:300px;
    top:100px; 
  left:120px; 
}
```

Then assign this class to CssClass property of both images control.. then Try different value of height,width..etc for overlapping the pregressbar image.

OR

you need to somehow set the Progressbar Images's Display property to 'none'.
like,

```
style="display:none;"
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks. But, I thinks <td> is still reserving some space beside textbox.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the code flow should like this in  ontextchanged event

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UpdateProgress1.Visible = true;

     // Existing code to check the user validation 

     UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;           

     // Existing code to display image according to validation success or failed
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but you didn't get my question. I was asking about space between textbox and image, as each image is in a different <td>